# For me, orthoM does same thing as frustumM (ie shows perspective)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am doing some 3D modelling which requires some slightly unusual transformations (essentially I need to do slant/skew transformations instead of rotates). As I have not done any opengl programming before, I used the 2D canvas drawing libraries and created my own 3D -> 2D transformation matrices for proof of concept. Works great using wireframe models.

To convert it to 3D, I used the SDK sample OpenGLS20Complete program which draws a square and a triangle. I modified this to abstract the draw method out as an interface (IDrawable) so I can process lists of IDrawables. For testing, I constructed a cube with 6 faces by forming a list of squares.

Everything works fine, except that the cube is obviously being drawn with perspective on, as the top face is larger than the bottom face. OrthoM returns a different matrix to frustumM (the matrix values are different) but is doing the same thing, as far as I can tell. I need an orthographic perspective for this application (ie no perspective). I can't get it to work.

I have stripped my code down to display a single cube for testing as follows:

The code in OpenGLS20Complete onSurfaceCreated  is:

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 

    transformedshapes = new ArrayList<IDrawable>();
            cubeSide = 0.3f;
    IDrawable cube1 = new Cube(-0.4f, cubeSide, -0.4f, cubeSide, 0f, cubeSide, Color.GRAY, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN);
    transformedshapes.add(cube1);

    // next line added by me
    GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );        
}
```

The Cube constructor Cube(left, cubewidth, right, cubelength, basez, cubeheight, ... six colors) simply creates 6 faces (as IDrawable objects), one of each of the 6 colors listed. Does what it is supposed to.

The OnSurfaceChanged code is:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / (float) height;
//      Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7); // original
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
 }
```

The results on the screen are the same whether I use the .frustumM or .orthoM method. Changing the values in the frustumM method changes the display as I would expect. And using the debugger, I can see the frustumM and orthoM methods prepare different matrices.

The OnDraw method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    // Draw untransformed shapes
    for (IDrawable shape:untransformedshapes)
        shape.draw(mMVPMatrix);

    float [] rotatedmMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    float netRotationAboutX = mAngleRotateAboutX - mAngleStartRotateAboutX;
    float netRotationAboutY = mAngleRotateAboutY - mAngleStartRotateAboutY;
    float netRotationAboutZ = mAngleRotateAboutZ - mAngleStartRotateAboutZ;      

    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, netRotationAboutY, 0, -1f, 0f);
    float[] xRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.setRotateM(xRotationMatrix, 0, netRotationAboutX, -1f, 0, 0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix, 0, xRotationMatrix, 0,
                mRotationMatrix, 0);


        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedmMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        for (IDrawable shape : transformedshapes)
            shape.draw(rotatedmMVPMatrix);


}
```

The above performs a rotation rather than a skew matrix to make it easier to debug. It works, in that the cube or cubes get rotated when I change mAngleRotateAboutX and mAngleRotateAboutY.

The method .setLookAtM() doesn't seem entirely appropriate to an orthographic projection. As there is no perspective required, the z distance (3 in this case) seems unnecessary. An orthographic projection should only require a direction (ie 2 independent variables) and not a view location (3 independent variables). Maybe I shouldn't be using this?

The squares which are part of my cube are instances of a PWRectShape class which implements the draw method of my IDrawable interface. This is a monkey-see-monkey-do modification of the square drawing method OpenGLS20Complete

```
class PWRectShape implements IDrawable{
private final String vertexShaderCode =
    // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
    // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "void main() {" +
    // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
    "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
    "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
    "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
// Set color with default red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };

public PWRectShape(float [] rectCoords, int colour) { // the constructor
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates

    color[0] = (float)Color.red(colour)/256f;
    color[1] = (float)Color.green(colour)/256f;
    color[2] = (float)Color.blue(colour)/256f;
    color[3] = 1f;      
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            rectCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(rectCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                                               vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                                                 fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {      // the draw method
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                          GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

There is additional code for setting up simple shaders etc, all of which is unchanged from OpenGLES20Complete. I can post it if necessary. But all this seems to work OK. In fact, everything works OK - I can draw multiple cubes at multiple locations, and even skew them correctly through a custom projection matrix. The only thing doesn't work is that the top faces of the cubes are larger than the bottom faces, it is obviously using perspective, whether I use .frustumM or .orthoM.

Any suggestions or ideas on why I get a perspective view and not an orthographic projection when this code is run?

Comment: Have you tried always using a w-coordinate of 1.0 in gl_Position? This will prevent the perspective divide from having any effect.

Comment: The only gl_Position in the code is in the vertex shader as part of the program string passed to the hardware. Tried changing this, but don't know what I'm doing and crashed the program. Of course orthoM works, but it doesn't in my program. Maybe I have some additional line somewhere which overrides it. I don't expect someone to debug my code for me; I only posted it because if I didn't somebody would ask for it anyway. I was more hoping somebody remembered similar behaviour in something they did, and could tell me why it happened.

Comment: Right, `gl_Position` is the output of the vertex shader. While GPUs are highly-programmable these days, there is one step that occurs even after you write your vertex position in a shader. The hardware does a perspective divide (that is, it divides `gl_Position.xyz` by `gl_Position.w`). Usually W will be 1.0 given a non-perspective projection matrix, but with all the non-standard matrix manipulation you spoke of in your question it is possible that you're winding up with a value other than 1.0 after transformation.

Comment: Thanks Andon. The test case (above) doesn't do any non-standard matrix manipulations, there is a rotate matrix but this is the identity matrix. Matrix.orthoM() produces a matrix mProjMatrix which looks right, mProjMatrix[15] = 1 (this is "w", right?). Matrix.setLookAtM() also does what I would expect, and the resulting mVMatrix[15] = 1. Their product is mMVPMatrix, and mMVPMatrix[15] = 1. As the rotation has no effect, this is the same matrix as handed to glUniformMatrix4fv and yes mMVPMatrix[15] = 1 at this point. Everything works exactly as expected, except I get perspective. Arrrrgh!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful an answer coming two years after the question - but it might help someone else.

In your `OnDrawFrame()` method you have this:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedmMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

Whereas I think you intend for your rotation transform to be applied first to transform objects in your scene, and then afterwards for the results to be transformed through the view and projection transforms.

That would require the order of the LHS and RHS to be inverted like this:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedmMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

As I suspect you know, when you [multiply matrices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#multiplyMM(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int)) it produces a new matrix that is equivalent to applying first the RHS to the input, then the LHS to the result from that.